# Unable to access image on live site?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, nginx

It's a simple "About Us" page that's generated by db:seed, I've tried `img src="public/assets/image.png"` and `img src="/assets/image.png"` but neither works.

Localhost:3000 is able to display the image. However, it does not work when I upload it to my AWS EC2 server.

It's running on nginx.

I've used the following:

Filezilla to upload images into project/app/assets/images/ and project/public/assets/

Terminal/ssh to `rake db:seed` in order to re-create the about-us page.
Terminal/ssh to `sudo service nginx restart`

I'm trying to locate the image.png I've added via filezilla. The directory of Filezilla and ls from Terminal suggests that it exists but I'm having a hard time locating the url of it.

I'm not too sure about security issues.

Comment: There can be so many things wrong. can you provide more details?
 It can be local firewall, AWS security groups or something wrong or incorrectly setup on that instance

Comment: edited main post due to formatting issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the asset pipeline in production, then you have to use the asset pipeline helpers (`image_tag`, `image_path`, or `asset_path`) to correctly reference your assets:

Suppose `image.png` exists as `app/assets/images/image.png`:

Then you would use the `image_tag` helper to reference `image.png`:

```
= image_tag "image.png"
```

This would correspond to the following HTML tag:

```
<img src="<%=image_path("image.png")%>">
```

Note that `image_path("filename")` maps to `asset_path("images/filename")`:

```
<img src="<%=asset_path("images/image.png")%>">
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time with using image_tags in this mess, what should I do to squeeze it into this mess?  http://i.imgur.com/IbNhc1S.png / http://i.imgur.com/Zkh90Sj.png

Comment: Why are you storing DOM content in your database? I wouldn't recommend doing so as this is going to be a huge liability if you want to change assets/styles in your views.

Comment: We hired an outsourced developer for the site, I just need to clean the site up before marketing it.

Comment: OK, got it. Based on the `public/assets/images/icon_buy.png` url in the code you've pasted in your image, you'll need to create a folder in your `public` folder named `public/assets/images/icon_buy.png`. Yes, that's a folder named `public` nested within your existing `public` folder so from your app directory this would be: `public/public/assets/images/icon_buy.png`. Also ensure `config.serve_static_files = true` in `production.rb` (or equivalent). This is really just a short-term solution and I'd seriously consider refactoring your asset-management in the near-future.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure if it matters but it's in .html.slim instead of .html.erb  The public/assets/images/icon_buy.png was changed by me to try and solve the image problem, it was originally empty.

Answer (score 0):

make sure is correct your image URL and finish upload to ser